# Stack Snippet editor doesn't close with the background fade

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

While I was answering a question on Stack Overflow I wanted to insert a snippet... but then I changed my mind and pressed on the grayed out space near the snippet window (without releasing the mouse, since my mind was still processing if I should answer or not).

This resulted in the gray area fading out, but leaving me with a white window in the middle.

> [image]

All sites using Stack Snippets seem to have this behavior.

Comment: No repro in Chrome on a Mac here. Please include your OS/browser.

Comment: @AnnaLear Tried it on Windows 8/7 with Chrome 37.0.2062.124. You don't have to actually click (mousedown/mouseup) just press on it for 1 second (mousedown)

Comment: Oh, just mousedown... yep, can repro that. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I have fixed the issue and now a `mousedown` will close the Stack Snippets editor. Previously, this functionality was bound to a `click` thus the demonstrated issue. This will be live in the next build (meta: > `rev 2014.10.2.2623`, q&a: > `rev 2014.10.2.1907`).

Comment: Looks like this may have created [another bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240486/snippets-editor-wont-insert-and-close-on-so).